# How can I turn off auto-completion in word processing apps?

Tags: microsoft-word, openoffice, autocomplete, openoffice-writer, autoindent

In both Word and Open Office, these word processors try to be clever and guess where you want to indent, or automatically complete a word you've started to type. In my experience, they are wrong a great majority of the time. IOW, this "help" is a cause of great frustration and irritation.

Does anybody know how to turn off this "help" in Open/Libre Office. I know MS Word does the same thing, but I don't use it anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For Word 2003:**

1. On the Insert menu, point to AutoText, and then click AutoText.
2. Clear the Show AutoComplete suggestions check box.

**For Word 2010:**

1. Office Button, click Word Options,
2. click Proofreading,
3. click Autocorrect Options
4. Clear the check boxes for the features that you want to disable

**For Open Office:**

1. Tools > AutoCorrect > Word Completion

Comment: Thanks, this is good for other people searching in the future. For me, though, it doesn't help much, as we use Open Office/Libre Office (my wife uses Open, I use Libre), not MS Word.

Comment: @ClayShannon Inserted an edit for the open office, see if that helps. Thanks.